# Why is my code not producing any (required) output at all? I need to find the maximum sum of 2D array elements while travelling in a zig-zag fashion

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

This code is not at all producing any output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 10
#define COL 10

void scanMatrix(int[ROW][COL], int, int);
void printMatrix(int[ROW][COL], int, int);

int maxSum(int[ROW][COL], int, int);

int main()
{
    int rows, columns;
    int matrix[ROW][COL];
    int RequiredSum;

    printf("Enter rows and columns of the matrix: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &rows, &columns);

    if (rows <= 0 || columns <= 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid inputs. Rows and Columns must be greater than 0");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Enter matrix elements:\n");
    scanMatrix(matrix, rows, columns);

    printf("Matrix elements are:\n");
    printMatrix(matrix, rows, columns);

    RequiredSum = maxSum(matrix, rows, columns);
    printf("Maximum sum: %d", RequiredSum);
}

void scanMatrix(int matrix[ROW][COL], int rows, int columns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
}

void printMatrix(int matrix[ROW][COL], int rows, int columns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int maxSum(int matrix[ROW][COL], int rows, int columns)
{
    int max_Iterations = rows + columns - 1;
    int current_Iteration = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    sum = sum + matrix[i][j]; // 'i' is row index. 'j' is column index

    while (current_Iteration <= max_Iterations)
    {
        if (i == (rows - 1))
            j++;
        else if (j == (columns - 1))
            i++;
        else if (matrix[i + 1][j] >= matrix[i][j + 1]) // Move down if right element is equal or less than below element
            i++;
        else if (matrix[i + 1][j] < matrix[i][j + 1]) // Move right if down element is less than right element
            j++;

        sum = sum + matrix[i][j];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The question is to find the maximum sum from [0][0] to [rows-1][rows-1]. We can either move downwards or to the right.

I can't even get any output. The matrix elements are displayed fine, but it stops after that. Required sum is not at all getting printed (not even the wrong value, if it is).

Comment: you never update `current_iteration` in your loop, so infinite loop, `maxSum` never returns, you never hit your `printf("Maximum sum: %d", RequiredSum)` line.

Comment: debugging tip: hardcode a matrix of values and ring out the rest of your code using that. It will be _soo_ much faster than entering fresh matrix values every test iteration. Once you're confident everything else is working correctly, bring back the user input.

Comment: thanks so much. I am still a beginner and mistakes like this make me want to drop out of life. thanks for correcting it so soon!

Comment: @Harish Patil  It is unclear what is   [rows-1][rows-1]. Do you mean   [rows-1][columns-1]?

Answer (score 2):

You're not updating `current_Iteration` in your `while` loop in `maxSum`.  This creates an infinite loop, so `maxSum` never returns, and you never hit your print out.  Increment `current_Iteration` each time through the loop:

```c
while (current_Iteration <= max_Iterations)
{
    ...
    sum = sum + matrix[i][j];
    // next iteration
    current_Iteration++;
}
```

There could be other problems, but this immediately addresses why you're not seeing the `RequiredSum` printout.

Comment: @Harish Also note that `stdout` is line-buffered by default (unless it's connected to an interactive device), so you need to add a `\n` in the calls to `printf()`, or call `fflush()` on the output stream.

Comment: @Haris good point. However, I do believe [`stdout` (and other buffers for that matter) get flushed when the process exits](https://godbolt.org/z/6o1xq8Y8M). Printing `RequiredSum` is the last thing this program does, so even tho the `'\n'` is missing, I'd still expect to see the final `printf`.  But yes, I agree, OP should add `'\n'` to that `printf`.